# What CDN features are the most important when picking a CDN provider?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, performance, cdn, page-speed

Price and a number of PoP's surely do matter.

But if I was after choosing one CDN provider out of 10 similar ones, what CDN features would be the most important?

Which ones do really matter for faster page load times and content delivery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the number of PoPs, for faster page load time you'll want to look at if the CDN provider provider offers SSD and [HTTP/2](https://http2.github.io/faq/) supported edge servers. Delivering content over HTTP/2 will allow you to use one connection for parallelism, enable header compression, among other things that will help speed up the delivery of your content.

Currently no browsers support HTTP/2 unless the connection is encrypted (TLS) therefore you may want to also look if the CDN offers Let's Encrypt integration (if you want to avoid purchasing an SSL certificate).

I would recommend checking out [cdncomparison.com](http://cdncomparison.com/) for a broad comparison overview of multiple CDN providers.

Answer (score 0):

THE MOST IMPORTANT CONSIDERATION is support for edns-client-subnet. No amount of pops, fast storage and http/2 support will speed up your site if your clients are not directed to the nearest pop.